# How can I write a library usable from multiple languages?

Tags: java, c#, cross-platform, transpiler, language-binding

I am trying to write a library which can be used from multiple programming languages, for example:

- CLR languages (C#, F#..)
- JVM languages (Java, Kotlin, Scala..)
- Native languages (C/C++, Rust, Objective-C, Swift..)
- JavaScript/TypeScript

The basic way I know to achieve this is to write it in C/C++ and maintain my own bindings for each language, or to maintain separate copies of the library for each language (like Reactive extensions does). Either way, that's *O(n)* work for *n* languages.

Is there a language or tool that I can use to write the library in one language and have bindings automatically generated for other languages?

Comment: Did you consider using webservices?

Comment: Of course you have to write some accessor that is able to deal with the input and output for your program. Having said this, that accessor is different for every language.

Comment: Look at SWIG. This is is goal. Keep in mind, however. That SWIG interfaces are never as good as a native library.

Comment: If it is not heavy usage, it might be easier, to write it as a separate executable, or script, and then call it - as a system call - from the other languages.  Defined the API as the command line args